# How would I create an index on this temp table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to speed up a query and I think I am confused about indexes. How, and what index would I add to this table. The ID is Unique, would this be a primary index?

```
CREATE TABLE #OSP
    (
        [Id] UniqueIdentifier,
        [YearMonth] int,
        [Expenditure] decimal (7,2),
        [Permit] decimal (7,2)
    );
```

Comment: If you're querying by Id, then yes, it'd be the primary key/index.  If you're not using it to query, the index won't help...

Comment: Then yes, it's the right primary index/key to create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're joining on id then creating an index on that would help.

I think this would work:

```
CREATE TABLE #OSP
    (
        [Id] UniqueIdentifier,
        [YearMonth] int,
        [Expenditure] decimal (7,2),
        [Permit] decimal (7,2)
    );


CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [idx_id] ON #Osp ([Id] ASC)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the [primary key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181043.aspx) in your [create table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) statement.

```
CREATE TABLE #OSP
    (
        [Id] UniqueIdentifier primary key,
        [YearMonth] int,
        [Expenditure] decimal (7,2),
        [Permit] decimal (7,2)
    );
```

Comment: +1 This is preferred as it makes the `#temp` table cacheable [and can reduce the number of `#temp` table creations](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic510942-360-1.aspx)